# MySQL muliplication output and Perl DBI

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, select, dbi

I am writing a Perl script that uses DBI to connect to a MySQL database. I am trying to `fetch` a column that is the value of a multiplication `SUM(amount, 365)` in MySQL the code works, and also in Perl the code works for `SUM(amount)`  My thoughts are that the multiplication is putting out a different type of value that I cannot read through my method. I could be off though, still pretty new to Perl.

Here is code

```
my ($sum, $sum365);

$sth = $dbh->prepare ("
    SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(amount) * 365)
    FROM spending 
    ");

$sth->execute()
    or die "cannot execute\n";

$sth->bind_col(1, \$sum);
$sth->bind_col(2, \$sum365);


while ( $sth->fetch ){
    print "$sum\n";
    print "$sum365\n";
}
```

Another work around I am thinking of, is there a way to have Perl read the value as numeric?  Then I could just create another variable `$sum365 = $sum * 365`.  I tried that too, but Perl is not reading the value as numeric.

Also I am aware there are different methods in Perl to `fetch` from database `array`, `arrayref` etc.  Is there another method that would work, and why?

Comment: I would recommend turning on [RaiseError] which will throw an error for every DBI method, not the the ones you remember to check.  `DBI->connect(..., { RaiseError => 1 })`;

Comment: Oh good advice, will that give specific errors? For instance with warning it will tell me that there was an error with at the line of `prepare`. Will `RaiseError => 1` give the exact reason? In this case there was no error though, it was just giving me a blank output and that is why I thought that Perl was not able to read the output.  I can read into it more too

Comment: It is strange that the execute did not die.  RaiseError will give you the same error message as [$DBI::errstr](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#errstr) which will be whatever error message comes from MySQL.  It should be something like `prepare failed: near ")"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant closing bracket (`)`) in your query after "365":

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("
    SELECT SUM(amount), SUM(amount) * 365
    FROM spending 
");
```

Comment: oh wow you are right.. swear I was at it for a while...thanks

Comment: I needed an extra bracket SUM((amount) * 365)